# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'password')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/User.js')

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('pages/register.ejs')
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password

    const newUser = new User({
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password
    })

    console.log(newUser.toJSON())

    newUser.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
            
        } else {
            res.send('user created successfully')
        }
    })

    User.findOne({  username:username, email: email, password: password }, (err, foundResult) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }else{
            if(foundResult.password === password && foundResult.email === email && foundResult.username === username){
                res.send('User yet created')
            }
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

In this code of a simple login and registration system I have taken what is entered in the password input and used it in such a way as to insert it into the DB. But when I submit the form to register it gives me this error

```
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'password')
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\project\fullstack\ecommerce\routes\registerRoute.js:34:28
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\project\fullstack\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4994:18
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\coding\project\fullstack\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4996:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Some ideas. Thanks too much

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better way to doing this.
If you use async/await version then must be in try/catch block..

```
router.post('/register' , async (req , res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // res.json({message: req.body});
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    if(!username || !email|| !password) {
        return res.status(422).json({error:"Please filled the field correctly"});
    }

    try {
        const userExist = await User.findOne({username:username});
        if (userExist) {
            res.send({message:"Username Already Exist !!!"});
            return res.status(422).json({error:"Username already Exist"});
        }

        const user = new User({ username , email , password});
        await user.save();
        res.status(201).json({ message:"User Registered Successfully!!" })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("showing errors" , err);
    }
})
```